# Simplifying This Summation - Need Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

For each $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, let
$S_m$ = $\sum_{k=0}^m 2^k{m \choose k}$.

If $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, determine the value of 
$$\frac{S_{n+1}}{S_n}$$

So far, I have simplified it down to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spf6t.jpg

I don't know how to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that according to the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) you have
$$\sum_{k=0}^m 2^k{m \choose k} = (2+1)^m$$

Comment: Sorry This may sound dumb but i can simplify that to 3^m right?

Comment: Exactly. This is what you can do. :-)

Comment: I see so the answer to my question is 3 :).

Comment: @JackFlower So it is :-)

Comment: @JackFlower You might like the following page (here an example with your exercise):
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+C(m,k)2%5Ek,+k%3D0..m